# how to save (insert) data in datatable from datagridview in vb.net step by step

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

I am creating code for inserting data from datagridview in vb.net to database table Access 2007. But the program is for inserting data from user when he input data in datagridview in 1st row then after next time (after break by break) he input data again on 2nd , 3rd next row and click on save button in my project to insert data in database.
but problem arises when he click on save 2nd time for inserting data into database the process code insert all row old & new again. it is not proper inserting. it repeats data.
So please suggest me Solution
I am using dt for datatable and sql for sql statement.

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM RABill "
        maxrow = get_maxrow(sql)

        For i = 0 To DgRAbill.Rows.Count - 2

            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM RABill  ")
            Dim strInsert As String = "INSERT INTO RABill (Billnumber,RDate,RAmount,Below,Royalti,SD,IT,GSTminus,RAccountname,GstTwelvepercent,Insurance,Other,TotalBill,Remark) VALUES ('" _
                                                                   & CStr(DgRAbill.Rows(i).Cells(1).FormattedValue) & "','" _
                                                                   & CStr(DgRAbill.Rows(i).Cells(2).FormattedValue) & "','" _
                                                                   & CStr(DgRAbill.Rows(i).Cells(3).FormattedValue) & "','" _
                                                                   & CStr(DgRAbill.Rows(i).Cells(4).FormattedValue) & "','" _
                                                                   & CStr(DgRAbill.Rows(i).Cells(5).FormattedValue) & "','" _
                                                                   & CStr(DgRAbill.Rows(i).Cells(6).FormattedValue) & "','" _
                                                                   & CStr(DgRAbill.Rows(i).Cells(7).FormattedValue) & "','" _
                                                                   & CStr(DgRAbill.Rows(i).Cells(8).FormattedValue) & "','" _
                                                                   & ComboBox1.Text & "','" _
                                                                   & CStr(DgRAbill.Rows(i).Cells(10).FormattedValue) & "','" _
                                                                   & CStr(DgRAbill.Rows(i).Cells(11).FormattedValue) & "','" _
                                                                   & CStr(DgRAbill.Rows(i).Cells(12).FormattedValue) & "','" _
                                                                   & CStr(DgRAbill.Rows(i).Cells(13).FormattedValue) & "','" _
                                                                   & CStr(DgRAbill.Rows(i).Cells(14).FormattedValue) & "')"
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(strInsert, conn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Record  Saved Successfully")
        Next

    End Sub
```

in above code my datagridview has extra row in it so it code is rows-2

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be clearing the variable 'strInsert' after the insert so this may be the issue you are facing?

I would be tempted to clear the variable after the MsgBox.

Many Thanks
POC

Comment: please decribe with example

Comment: i have tried your solution and clear "strInsert" after msgbox but it not used the record is repated to save

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of concerning things with your code snippet here.

1. Is your database suppose to be able to have duplicate entries? You might want to look at how your primary keys are set up.
2. You should really have some error catching in here, especially with database connections. Take a look through this for reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/try-catch-finally-statement
3. As for the actual double entry - you're not clearing out your datagridview after saving all the records. If I'm understanding correctly the user fills in a bunch of rows in the DGV then hits save and it loops through and inserts them all. Then he continues entering and hits save again and it inserts all of them (some duplicates).  After saving you should do a .Clear on your DGV - or you need to create some kind of counter that persists between saves and that's where you'll start your for loop at in the save button Below is clearing it after each save:

   ```
   Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
   Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM RABill "
   maxrow = get_maxrow(sql)

   For i = 0 To DgRAbill.Rows.Count - 2

       Try
           Dim strInsert As String = "INSERT INTO RABill (Billnumber,RDate,RAmount,Below,Royalti,SD,IT,GSTminus,RAccountname,GstTwelvepercent,Insurance,Other,TotalBill,Remark) VALUES ('" _
                                                              & CStr(DgRAbill.Rows(i).Cells(1).FormattedValue) & "','" _
                                                              & CStr(DgRAbill.Rows(i).Cells(2).FormattedValue) & "','" _
                                                              & CStr(DgRAbill.Rows(i).Cells(3).FormattedValue) & "','" _
                                                              & CStr(DgRAbill.Rows(i).Cells(4).FormattedValue) & "','" _
                                                              & CStr(DgRAbill.Rows(i).Cells(5).FormattedValue) & "','" _
                                                              & CStr(DgRAbill.Rows(i).Cells(6).FormattedValue) & "','" _
                                                              & CStr(DgRAbill.Rows(i).Cells(7).FormattedValue) & "','" _
                                                              & CStr(DgRAbill.Rows(i).Cells(8).FormattedValue) & "','" _
                                                              & ComboBox1.Text & "','" _
                                                              & CStr(DgRAbill.Rows(i).Cells(10).FormattedValue) & "','" _
                                                              & CStr(DgRAbill.Rows(i).Cells(11).FormattedValue) & "','" _
                                                              & CStr(DgRAbill.Rows(i).Cells(12).FormattedValue) & "','" _
                                                              & CStr(DgRAbill.Rows(i).Cells(13).FormattedValue) & "','" _
                                                              & CStr(DgRAbill.Rows(i).Cells(14).FormattedValue) & "')"
           cmd = New OleDbCommand(strInsert, conn)
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
           MsgBox("Record  Saved Successfully")
           DgRabill.Rows.Clear()
       Catch ex As Exception
           MessageBox.Show("Error Inserting record at row " & i & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
       End Try

   Next

   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to bind and save your DataGridView data to your database.

```
Dim connString As String = ""
Private ds As DataSet
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ds = New DataSet()

    Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connString)
        con.Open()
        Dim adp As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from RABill", con)
        adp.Fill(ds)
        Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    End Using
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connString)
        con.Open()
        Dim adp As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from RABill", con)
        Dim build As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adp)
        adp.Update(ds.Tables(0))
    End Using
End Sub
```

Whatever you edit in your DataGridView, click button1 those records will be saved in the database.